# What is wrong with my ASP.NET MVC SelectList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

I'm trying to use a SelectList one of my views, and its just not populating correctly.  It gets the proper number of entries (4), but they all read `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`.  I fired up the debugger on the code, and saw some strangeness going on.  I must be doing something wrong, but I don't quite see what.

Code from the ViewModel:

```
public SelectList DeviceTypes {get; private set;}
....
var device_types = DataTableHelpers.DeviceTypes(); 
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> sl = device_types.Select(
                      dt => new SelectListItem { Selected = (dt.DeviceType == 1),
                      Text = dt.Description, 
                      Value = dt.DeviceType.ToString() }).ToList();
DeviceTypes = new SelectList(sl);
```

And code from the View:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Type",Model.DeviceTypes) %>
```

So, when I look at this in the debugger, the sl IEnumerable is getting built correctly.  I can see all 4 elements in there, with the proper Text and Value property values.  Once I call the SelectList constructor however, if I expand the IEnumerable that it contains, I see that it has 4 entries, but all the data in them has been lost.  The Text is set to `System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem`, and the value is `null`.

Ive tried changing the `ToList()` call to a `ToArray()`, as well as removing it entirely.  That didn't change the behaviour.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Scratch my first answer.

You should be passing the IEnumerable list if items to the View, not trying to construct a Html item in the controller.

Code for controller:

```
public IEnumberable<YourModel> DeviceTypes {get; internal set;}
....
DeviceTypes = DataTableHelpers.DeviceTypes();
```

Code for View:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Type", from dt in Model.DeviceTypes
                              select new SelectListItem
                              {
                                  Text = dt.Description,
                                  Value = dt.DeviceType.ToString(),
                                  Selected = dt.DeviceType == 1
                              }) %>
```

Comment: Yep, that did it, thanks.  I think I see what I was doing wrong now, too.

Comment: This is an old and functionnal answer, but please, **NEVER** write a Linq request directly into the view !! Good practice would be to declare an `int SelectedValue` and an `IEnumerable<> YourEnumerableProperty` properties in the Model, then fill it in the Controller, and finally use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedValue, new SelectList(Model.YourEnumerableProperty, "Value", "Text")`. Views are not supposed to hold logic business.

Comment: Views can contain logic, it just needs to be display logic instead of business logic.