# MVC 5 Razor - Listbox that displays items passed in a Viewbag list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am passing a ViewBag list to my view and I am trying to display this list in a listbox so as I can select items of this list.

This is the controller method for the view:

```
 public ActionResult AddMembers(int? id)
        {
            ViewBag.lstMembers = db.ClubMembers.ToList();

            var selClub = db.Clubs.Find(id);
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            return View(selClub);

        }
```

This is what I have currently but it is not displaying the items correctly as shown in the photo below:

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ClubMembers, new SelectList ( ViewBag.lstMembers))
```

[image]

How can I set the source of my listbox so that it will display the items passed in via the ViewBag.lstMembers from the controller method

Comment: You need to specify the display member and value member that will be used to render the string representation of the object, otherwise MVC will just call `ToString`. `SelectList` has an overloaded constructor for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is wrong with my ASP.NET MVC SelectList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082069/what-is-wrong-with-my-asp-net-mvc-selectlist)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the display member and value member that will be used to render the string representation of the object, otherwise MVC will just call `ToString`.

`SelectList` has an overloaded constructor for this e.g.:

```
new SelectList(items, "ValuePropertyName", "DisplayPropertyName")
```

see here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.SelectList.

Answer (score 3):

you can use MultiSelectList some thing like that 
In Action

```
ViewBag.lstMembers = new MultiSelectList(db.ClubMembers.ToList(), "ValueProperty", "NameProperty");
```

in View

```
@Html.ListBox("lstMembers", ViewBag.lstMembers as MultiSelectList)
```